# Поиск в массиве

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Есть такой код

```
switch (true) {
                case in_array(event.which, [37, 65]): // left
                    this.vec_add(this.velocity, {
                        x: -1,
                        y: 0
                    });
                    break;
                case in_array(event.which, [38, 87]): // top
                    this.vec_add(this.velocity, {
                        x: 0,
                        y: -1
                    });
                    break;
                case in_array(event.which, [39, 68]): // right
                    this.vec_add(this.velocity, {
                        x: 1,
                        y: 0
                    });
                    break;
                case in_array(event.which, [40, 83]): // bottom
                    this.vec_add(this.velocity, {
                        x: 0,
                        y: 1
                    });
                    break;
            }
```

Хочу переписать функцию на ES6

```
function in_array(el, array) {
    if (array.indexOf(el) != -1) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Делаю так

```
let test = [1,2,4,6,7,9];
console.log(test.find(x => x == 6));
```

не работает
так работает

```
let test = [1,2,4,6,7,9];
console.log(test.find(x => x > 6));//7
```

**Как можно проще переписать?**

В общем пока писал, так возвращает 6

```
console.log(test.find(x => x === 6 ));
```

нужно как то true  вернуть

```
console.log(test.find(x =>x === 6) > 0 ? true : false); //true
```

Comment: ну вообще как я понял вы хотите [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) из ES5 либо [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) из ES7

Comment: вот этот код `console.log(test.find(x => x == 6));` в хроме работает нормально

Comment: @Grundy а сам switch  как то проще можно записать, точнее более правильно, я компилю через grunt  он валится если просто 2-е равно

Comment: а над объектом `{
                        x: 0,
                        y: 1
                    }` какие-то действия будут производится или значения его полей не будут меняться?

Comment: вообще можно заменить на простой цикл

Comment: @Grundy хотя странно сейчас попробовал он перестал валиться, космическая радиация похоже =) Над объектом нет не будут в этом месте так точно не планирую

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы успростить всю конструкцию, можно воспользоваться свойстами switch-case, тогда необходимость в использовании дополнительной функции отпадет:

```
switch (event.which) {
  // left
  case 37:
  case 65:
    this.vec_add(this.velocity, { x: -1, y: 0 });
    break;

  // top
  case 38:
  case 87:
    this.vec_add(this.velocity, { x: 0, y: -1 });
    break;

  // right
  case 39:
  case 68:
    this.vec_add(this.velocity, { x: 1, y: 0 });
    break;

  // bottom
  case 40:
  case 83:
    this.vec_add(this.velocity, { x: 0, y: 1 });
    break;

  default:
    break;
}
```

Для пояснения - в случае, если условие для `case` выполняется, то будет выполнен весь код в его блоке. Если в блоке отсутствует ключевое слово `break`, то также будет выполнен и код всех последующих `case` пока не встретится `break`. Например:

```
case 37:
case 65:
  this.vec_add(this.velocity, { x: -1, y: 0 });
  break;
```

если срабатывает первый `case 37:`, то выполняется его блок - в данном случае он абсолютно пуст (это корректно), `break` тоже отсутствует, следовательно будет также выполнен следующий `case 65:` - в нем есть `break`, что наконец прервет выполнение и следующие ситуации отработаны не будут.

Подробнее на MDN - [switch](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)

Comment: не знал что так можно =)

Answer (score 1):

Отчего бы не написать всё простыми условиями?

```
let move = {x:0, y:0}, code = event.which;
if( code === 37 || code === 65) move.x = -1;
else if( code === 38 || code === 87) move.y = -1;
else if( code === 39 || code === 68) move.x = 1;
else if( code === 40 || code === 83) move.y = 1;
this.vec_add( this.velocity, move);
```

---

**P.S.** чтобы через неделю действительно не разобраться, можно так записать в три строчки всё:

```
let index = [37,65,39,68,38,87,40,83].indexOf(event.which), move={x:0,y:0};
if(!!~index) move[index&4?'y':'x'] = index&2?1:-1;
this.vec_add( this.velocity, move);
```

Comment: так хуже читается

Comment: зато быстрее исполняется : )

Comment: это да, но я через неделю не пойму что я тут писал =)

Comment: комментарии помогут.

Answer (score 1):

Простите, но что вам мешает переписать это:

```
function in_array(el, array) {
    if (array.indexOf(el) != -1) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Как минимум, на вот это:

```
function in_array(el, array) {
    return array.indexOf(el) != -1;
}
```

?

Если вам хочется ES6 и покороче, то ваш пример будет таким:

```
console.log(!!~(test.findIndex(x => x === 6)));
```

То есть, в функции, фактически, это может быть и вот так:

```
function in_array(el, array) {
    return !!~(array.findIndex(x => x === el));
}
```

Но только зачем? Менее читабельно же.

Comment: findIndex - разве не индекс в массиве ищет?

Comment: @SergeEsmanovich его и ищет. Сколь я помню, это аналог indexOf. !!~ — приводит -1 в false, 1 в true.

Comment: @SergeEsmanovich, это тоже самое что и indexOf, за исключением того, что _indexOf_ принимает элемент. который надо найти. а _findIndex_ проверяет условие

Comment: @IgorAdamenko вот console.log(!!~test.indexOf(6)); это самое то =) не знал что так можно, а вот так ещё и читается норм console.log(!!~test.find(x =>x == 6)); Поставлю пока плюсик, может кто нить ещё круче вариант предложит